# Connected 2-Pin Button switching randomly from LOW to HIGH

Tags: arduino

I got this ordinary 2-pin push button and now I'm trying to read its state.
Basically I want to turn a LED on and off.

My board is an Arduino Uno and the button is connected to GND and *Digital Pin 2*.
Also Pin 2 is configured as `INPUT_PULLUP`.
I followed the instructions in [this](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/InputPullupSerial) tutorial.

My issues:

- `digitalRead(2)` returns randomly `LOW` and `HIGH`
- It seems like there's no pullup resistor configured even though it's definitely in the code
- When I take the button in my hands and touch some parts it seems to work?

Questions:

- The button is connected to GND. There are also other components connected to the same GND. Could there be too much connected to GND?
- Do you have any ideas what I did wrong?
- Could my Arduino be broken/fried?

**Update:**

[Here](http://www.produktinfo.conrad.com/datenblaetter/700000-724999/701120-da-01-en-Drucktaster_R13_516A_02.pdf) is the datasheet for the button I bought.

Comment: Can you measure a voltage on the input without anything else connected?

Comment: Yes, I can do this tonight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trouble may well be in the switch itself since it's not designed for the low-current switching your circuit needs, and is designed to switch fairly high voltages and currents.

In normal use those kinds of switches generate arcs when the contacts open and/or bounce, and those arcs blast off non-conducting films which can otherwise accumulate on the contacts and cause trouble.

The problem is that the low voltage and current levels you're trying to switch just don't have the power to blast off all of the non-conducting film that can build up on the contacts, which will leave you with intermittent contacts and the problems you're experiencing.

Instead of exercising the switch, try shorting across the pins on the Arduino with a clip lead or something and, if you get reliable operation, the switch will more than likely be the problem.

Comment: The button apparently only has 2 pins.

Comment: All, or nearly all of those types of switches have 4 pins, though they may not pin out how one expects.

Comment: Nothing comes to mind when I try to figure out an orientation for a 4-pin tactile switch that would leave it permanently open.

Comment: Two pins connected to the switch and the other two pins left open, but used to solder the switch into the PCB would leave you with a permanent open if the wrong two pins were chosen as the switched pins.

Comment: It's a button with two pins, I added the datasheet.

Comment: @JulianHollmann: The trouble may well be in the switch itself, then, since it's not designed for the low-current switching your circuit needs.  The problem is that the low voltage and  current levels you're trying to switch just don't have the power to blast off all of the  non-conducting film that can build up on the contacts, which will leave you with intermittent contacts and the problems you're experiencing.  Try shorting across the pins on the Arduino - with a clip lead or something - which the switch normally would and, if you get reliable operation, the switch will be the problem.

Comment: That's a good idea, thanks. Could you maybe edit your answer?

Comment: @JulianHollmann: Done.

Answer (score 1):

That button won't have an internal pull-up resistor (it's rated for250VAC with a breakdown of 1500V AC!) - you need an external pull-up resistor and also take note what EM_Fields says about voltage and current - try it with a 1k ohm pull-up but don't expect miracles and do expect severe contact bounce to cause multiple false triggers.

Comment: "Pin 2 is configured as INPUT_PULLUP" -- Shouldn't that obviate an external pull-up?

Comment: @HannoBinder is your comment for me or for the OP?

Comment: I was referring to your statement "you need an external pull-up". However, I see that the internal pull-up (50kOhm+, IIRC) may not be strong enough for the switch.

Answer (score 0):

If it looks like the internal pull-up isn't working, what happens if you add an external one? Maybe that's the better design: use an external pull-up resistor. Your note "When I take the button in my hands and touch some parts it seems to work" makes me think that there's no pull-up at all, and the input is floating.